# How can we monitor the page views on my community (not sites)

Tags: community

I wish to get a count of total page hits on my community (For authenticated and unauthenticated users).

As per this document:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_communities_sites_limits.htm&language=en_US

I can get the limit to sites page views.

I wish to know the same for Community pages. (Setup>>Customize>>Communities)

Please assist me on this request.

Thanks!

Comment: Use Google Analytics. https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/?authuser=0#provision/SignUp/ . You have add the script code provided to your Community HEAD section. This can be done from Community Builder. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=community_builder_page_head.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community dashboards from the appexchange give you this. You can install the from the community management section for each community.

It's page views.  Plus a lot of other community features (posts, logins, topics, etc).

For way cooler stuff like "where are they coming from?", "what pages are they viewing in what order", "what demographics and interest categories are my users" and much more, use GoogleAnalytics.